How to use captcha token with signInWithPassword of supabase?
I have users trying to mass-sign-in to my system I build and authenticate with supabase. and they do have support for captcha token like hCaptcha. but i can't figure out how to use the token for a sign in with password method?
Here's is the code i've found in their documentation:
supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({
    email,
    password,
  });

help!!
I read their docs, ask in their community but in vain

Please link the mentioned documentation to make helping you easier. Also a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example would be nice. Where did you ask, a link might be good.

@Turing Vang Please explain, What do you mean by mass-sign-in, one user signing in from many devices ?

here's is an example, i've also add a check for dev env as the captch don't work for localhost:
  const signInObject:SignInObject = {
    email,
    password,
    options: {}
  };

  if(!isDev() && captchaToken) {
    signInObject.options = {
      captchaToken
    };
  }

  const { error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword(signInObject);


sometime i used gpteachus to learn about nextjs and supabase and it help me with this problem. anyway, good luck!!

Their reference documentation for this function states the parameters and that there is an options property that has a captchaToken option https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-signinwithpassword. They also have another doc about HCaptcha https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-captcha?queryGroups=captcha-method&captcha-method=hcaptcha-2
